# jquery append not add dynamic data

Tags: php, jquery

I am using this code with ajax

```
success: function(data) {

            result="<span class='profile-tag'id='personal_"+data+">"+$('#new_tag').val()+"</span>";
            $('#all_tag').append(result);
            $("#new_tag").val('');

}
```

when i write static data into in span tag it is working fine and append in all_tag but with dyanamic data whic is fetch through ajax will not show on html page. can any body know what is the reason ?

Comment: Try `result="<span class='profile-tag' id='personal_"+data+"'>"+$('#new_tag').val()+"</span>"`, there is a `'` missing in the `id` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
result="<span class='profile-tag' id='personal_"+data+"'>"+$('#new_tag').val()+"</span>"
```

there is a `'` missing in the `id` attribute

Answer (score 3):

Please check the result syntax first

```
result="<span class='profile-tag'id='personal_"+data+">"+$('#new_tag').val()+"</span>";
```

the single quote (') for id is not closed please close it first.

Answer (score 0):

result variable should be like below:- (there is quote problem in your code)

```
    result='<span class="profile-tag" id="personal_"'+ $("#new_tag").val() +'> </span>';
```